# On entry to SGEMM parameter number 8 had an illegal value

Tags: c++, c, matrix-multiplication, blas

I am trying to explore cblas library ; so i tried 2d matrix multiplication using Level3 **cblas_sgemm** routine.

```
C=(alpha)* A * B + (beta) * C
;; where aplha=1 & beta=0
```

```
#define TYPE float
#define A_R 3
#define A_C 2
#define B_R 2
#define B_C 3

    int main()
    {
        TYPE *A=NULL,*B=NULL,*C=NULL;
        if(A_C != B_R)
                {
                printf("\nA(%d,%d) X B(%d,%d) not possible\n",A_R,A_C,B_R,B_C);
                exit(1);
                }

        A=(TYPE*)malloc(A_R*A_C*sizeof(TYPE));
        B=(TYPE*)malloc(B_R*B_C*sizeof(TYPE));
        C=(TYPE*)malloc(A_R*B_C*sizeof(TYPE));
        initM(A,B,C);//initializes matrix
        cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,A_R, B_C,A_C, 1.0, A,A_R, B, B_R,0.0, C, A_C);
        //multiply(A,B,C);

        printf("\n%f\n",C[ (A_R*B_C)-1]);
}
```

I compiled my program using static libraries :

```
gcc mxm_blas.c -L/CBLAS/lib/ -lcblas -L/BLAS/ -lblas -I/CBLAS/include/ -lgfortran
```

Now running the code, i get :

> **On entry to SGEMM parameter number  8 had an illegal value**

It seems to me that trouble is with the way of declaring array! Most of the examples  [i have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747720/cblas-dgemm-works-only-if-beta-is-power-of-two) declare array as:

```
float A[100][100],b[100][100],C[100][100];
```

Is this the cause of the error or there is a programmatic error? Is malloc based matrix multiplication via the sgemm API not possible?

**UPDATE:** initM initializes the matrix :

```
void initM(TYPE* A,TYPE* B,TYPE* C)
{
long int i,j;

j=A_R*A_C;
for(i=0;i<j;i++) A[i]=2;

j=B_R*B_C;
for(i=0;i<j;i++)  B[i]=3;

j=A_R*B_C;
for(i=0;i<j;i++)  C[i]=0;
 }
```

Comment: That's a runtime error about values in `A`? What does `initM(A,B,C)` do? How does it know what size the arrays are?

Comment: @WeatherVane  i have added the initM function body, size of array is substituted at preprocessing phase!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is produced by `sgemm` and not `cblas_sgemm`. The number 8 parameter of `sgemm` is :

> SUBROUTINE SGEMM(TRANSA, TRANSB, M, N, K, ALPHA, A, **LDA**, B, LDB, BETA, C, LDC)

The C function cblas_sgemm is just a wrapper calling the Fortran routine sgemm. Bascally it converts some arguments passed from `by value` to `by reference`. Also, the Fortran routine is missing "RowMajor" parameter.

Since you are using "RowMajor" storage, you should use the number of columns as the leading dimension of the matrices.

Even if I can not test it, I suggest:

```
cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,A_R, B_C, A_C, 1.0, A, A_C, B, B_C, 0.0, C, B_C);
```

Also, you can refer to GSL [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/GSL-CBLAS-Examples.html).

Comment: tried your suggestion ; now i am getting **On entry to SGEMM parameter number 13 had an illegal value**!

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to ctheo's answer:

```
A[A_R][A_C] X B[B_R][B_C]=C[A_R][B_C] //if (A_C==B_R)
```

so, on setting the last parameter as **LDC**=B_C , the code works fine

```
cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,A_R, B_C,A_C,1.0, A,A_C, B, B_C,0.0, C,   B_C  );
```